# Cannot import Request and Response classes from okhttp

Tags: java, android, cordova, okhttp

I'm working on an Android app using cordova. I have a custom plugin which is attempting to use OkHttp.

In it, here's a relevant collection of imports:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request; // line 36
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response; // line 38
```

I'm hitting this error during build:

```
[javac] /path/to/class/SomeClass.java:36: error: Request is not public in com.squareup.okhttp; cannot be accessed from outside package
[javac] import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
[javac]                           ^
[javac] /path/to/class/SomeClass.java:38: error: Response is not public in com.squareup.okhttp; cannot be accessed from outside package
[javac] import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
[javac]                           ^
```

I'm using the latest available jar file - `okhttp-2.0.0.jar`, latest Java JDK version (`1.8.0_20`), etc.

What am I missing? Looking through the okhttp's source code, and their examples, these classes are certainly Public. Moreover, my other imports from `com.squareup.okhttp` are going through just fine...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that cordova ships with its own version of okhttp, currently v1.3 - which is old, and has largely different APIs. Namely, Request and Response classes aren't public.

My problem was that the jar of okhttp v2 I was including in my cordova plugin wasn't being used by the compiler. Not wanting to deal with those problems, I've updated my code to be inline with v1.3, and [filed a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7603) for updating version of okhttp to 2+ in Cordova's issue tracker.

Comment: How did you update your okhttp usage in 1.3.0 ? What are you using when you can't access Request or Response classes ?

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your App level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.4'
}
```